# What is the best position to put my Air Conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a problem. I have no idea where I should put the air conditioner to maximize it's effect. Here's a floor plan:

[image]

I'd love if the AC could cool down the whole floor, but that's not going to be possible because there isn't gonna be enough air flow (I think). What's a good position to put it into?

Comment: What kind of air conditioner? Window, portable, mini-split, or traditional/ducted?

Comment: A windows AC, just like this one http://www.tepeh.si/image/klime/Mitsubishi/HJ-serija/Komplet.jpg

Comment: That's not a window air conditioner. That's a mini-split.

Comment: Then a mini-split. I'm not a native english speaker so i wasn't that familiar with the expressions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is primarily opinion-based, since the answer depends on what makes you most comfortable.

As a person never short on opinions, I suggest this:

[image: modified from OP image]

Put the AC in the window at (1) and leave the doors to the master bedroom and the kitchen open. Purchase an inexpensive pedestal fan like this:

[image: source: www.homedepot.com]

and place it at (2) blowing in the direction of the arrow. Adjust the pedestal to its minimum height so the fan blows mostly through the lower half of the open door.

At night or on cool days turn off the fan and close the door.

EDIT: You could also put the AC at the other end of the house, with the fan blowing toward the master bedroom. Which is better depends on whether you need the cooling more during the times when you would be using the kitchen, or during the times when you would be using the master bedroom.

Where I live, in the late summer it remains too hot at night to sleep comfortably. Hence I would put the AC in the bedroom.

Comment: That's a good idea. I like it. Won't the cold air go down the stairs altho?

Comment: Yes cold air will go down the stairs; there's not much you can do about that. Keep the door at the bottom of the stairs closed.

Comment: Well there is no door at the bottom. Just a hallway leading into the main living room (no door again). Wouldn't it make more sense to put the AC into the big room?

Comment: Yes you can put the AC in the big room with the fan blowing toward the master bedroom. The same amount of cold air will go down the stairs.